# Can I make a smoke emission only be affected by a specific force field?

Tags: smoke-simulation, force-fields

I'd like to animate a scene where two different smoke emissions are in the same vicinity but are affected by different force fields. Can this be done?

Right now both emitters are in the same smoke domain, in case that's important.

Comment: Yes, this can be done, but only if you use separate smoke domains

Comment: @gandalf3 can the two domains overlap?

Comment: Yes, but smoke in the domains won't interact. Also emitters will emit in any domain that they intersect, so you'll have to make sure that the emitters stay in the correct domain.

Comment: @gandalf3 that can be done. You should put this information into an answer. It solved my problem. Once you pointed out the domains being separate, I realized where to look (Others might, however, appreciate being shown that part).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify a group of force fields which can affect the domain.

[image]

So by putting each force field in a separate group (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>), you can have them influence some domains but not others:

[image]